# If I have an array of values, how do I join some together separated by a dash?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array that looks like this:

```
array1 = button.attr('id').split('-');
["slider", "step", "value", "speed", "rebecca", "nitzsche", "st", "george", "s", "college"]
```

What I want to do is to take every element after `speed`, so everything after `array1[3]` to the end, and mush it all into 1 string separated by a `-` so it looks like this: `rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and then [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), like so:

```
var array = ["slider", "step", "value", "speed", "rebecca", "nitzsche", "st", "george", "s", "college"];
array.slice(4).join('-')

// It will return => "rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college"
```

Comment: Perfect. This is just what I was looking for. Thanks much!